# How to pass arguments in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue with the code below, it takes no argument, and i am suppose to create a method to return the answer. I don't know how to get the value passed. 
And please what is the name of this concept, so i can read it up.

```
describe "reverser" do
it "reverses the string returned by the default block" do
  result = reverser do
    "hello"
  end
  result.should == "olleh"
end
end

def reverser(sent)
words = sent.split(" ")
  i = 0
  while i < words.length
   words[i] = words[i].reverse
   i += 1
  end
  words.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reverser takes a block which you call to get it return value:

```
def reverser(&block)
  string = block.call
  string.reverse
end
```

Note: You do not need the `string` variable. I just use it for readability reasons. You can also just write `block.call.reverse`.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw the "yield" implementation

Comment: Block.call is two times slower than yield. Please be aware of that.

Comment: As I wrote: I aimed for readability and tried to make my solution easy to understand. Performance was not my priority.

Answer (score 3):

```
def reverser
  yield.reverse
end
```

Here is the code in question:

```
result = reverser do
  "hello"
end
```

That is equivalent to:

```
result = reverser() do
  "hello"
end
```

Breaking that down:

```
    method call -+      +- 'do' marks the start of the block
                 |      |
                 V      V 
    result = reverser() do
      "hello"
    end
     ^
     |
     +--- end of the block
```

A block is like a method, and it's as if the block is passed as an invisible argument to the reverse() method.  Inside reverse(), you can call the block using `yield`:

```
def reverser
  return_value_of_block = yield
  return_value_of_block.reverse
end
```

Writing `yield`, or `yield()`, is like writing `unamed_block_method()`. In other words, `yield` is the name ruby gives to the block-method.

And if the block is supposed to take arguments, then the block will look like this:

```
result = do_stuff do |x|
  x * 2
end
```

And do_stuff() will look like this:

```
def do_stuff
  return_value_of_block = yield(4)  #call block with the argument 4
end
```

> And please what is the name of this concept, so i can read it up.

Search for `ruby blocks`.

Comment: Explicitly return is not necessary here.